# Connect to a remote OSGI (Equinox) container

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, equinox

I am running a java application using equinox as OSGI container on a remote machine. I am able to debug remotely with eclipse, however, i am not able to use the usual osgi console from within eclipse. Since i was not able to find any good resources covering this topic, does anybody here have any advice on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You mean the OSGi console that you can define with -Dosgi.console=XXXX where XXXX is the port number? In case yes, check on the server that equinox is listening on that port ("netstat -l -n" on linux, on windows it is netstat but maybe with other parameters) and if you can access it from the client with telnet. In case it listens but not accessible you will have a firewall issue.

Comment: I solved the problem by running the application in a shell and enabling the local osgi console there. However, i guess that this is probably the parameter which enabled what i originally wanted. Will try it on occasion and report back here! Tank you!